# How to set preference in text search index to enable substring Persian text

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, full-text-search, text-search

To have the ability to use sub string search in text search indexing, i used following preference but it doesn't work for Persian texts, instead searching English text works great.
Create preference:

```
begin 
  ctx_ddl.create_preference('a_lex', 'AUTO_LEXER');
end;

begin
  ctx_ddl.create_preference('mywordlist', 'BASIC_WORDLIST');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mywordlist','PREFIX_INDEX','YES');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mywordlist','PREFIX_MIN_LENGTH',1);
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mywordlist','SUBSTRING_INDEX', 'YES');

  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mywordlist','FUZZY_MATCH','AUTO');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mywordlist','FUZZY_SCORE','1');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mywordlist','FUZZY_NUMRESULTS','5000');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mywordlist','STEMMER','AUTO');
end;
```

Indexing Query :

```
create index test on myTable(name) 
indextype is ctxsys.context online
parameters (
       'SYNC (on commit)
       LEXER a_lex
       MEMORY 200M 
       Wordlist mywordlist
       ') parallel 4;
```

Populated Data:  myTable { id : 1 , Name : رفتن }

```
select name from  myTable where contains(name,'%رفت%')>0
```

Comment: Problem solved by setting `World_Lexer` instead of `Auto_Lexer`.